# Solving vector equation

Tags: vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry

Suppose I know the following 3 normalized vectors in 3-D Euclidean space:

$\frac{\vec{A}}{||\vec{A}||}$,

$\frac{ \vec{A} + \vec{B}}{||\vec{A} + \vec{B}||}$

$\frac{ \vec{A} + \vec{C}}{||\vec{A} + \vec{C}||}$

Is it possible to determine the 3 unknown vectors $\vec{A}, \vec{B}, \vec{C}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Take $A=(\alpha, 0)$,  $B=(0, \alpha)$, $C=(-\beta,0)$  with $ \beta>\alpha >0$. Your three vectors end up the same for all values of the parameters.